# Split array into separate objects based on unique attributes

Tags: powershell

I have an array that I'm populating by some other means. It essentially contains this sample data;

```
PSComputerName              ResourceName   InstanceName       InDesiredState ConfigurationName StartDate          
--------------              ------------   ------------       -------------- ----------------- ---------          
server1.domain.local WindowsFeature Backup             True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:23
server1.domain.local Registry       fDenyTSConnections True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:23
server1.domain.local Registry       UserAuthentication True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:23
server1.domain.local File           DscDemo            True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:23
server5.domain.local WindowsFeature Backup             True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:23
server5.domain.local Registry       fDenyTSConnections True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:24
server5.domain.local Registry       UserAuthentication True           BaseConfig        24/04/2018 14:31:24
```

This is dynamic, and I'll have no idea when the array is populated what data will be inside. I need to split the array, into unique arrays (or PSObjects) based on the PSComputerName.

So in this case, I'd need to end up with two seperate objects/arrays for `server1` and `server5`, bearing in mind there could be 6 servers or 80 servers. I can't think of the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just group the data and work on each group individually? Assuming `$objects` contains the data in the question

```
$objects | Group-Object pscomputername | Foreach-object{
    $_.Group
}
```

Each `$_.Group` will be a collection of entries associated to a unique computer. `$_.Name` would be the pscomputername of the current grouped item.

So you might need to have another inner loop to iterate of those results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore, not sure why I was banging my head against a wall.

```
$Servers = $CSV.PSComputerName | select -Unique

ForEach($server in $Servers){

    $arr = $CSV | Where-Object {$_.PSComputerName -eq $server}

    Write-Host "Compliancy for $Server"
    $arr
    Write-Host "End compliancy for $server"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[group-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object). See "Example 4: Group event log events by ID"